# C++ inline assembly: how to deal with references?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, reference, inline-assembly

How to deal with references in function from inline assembler? I'm trying this

```
void foo(int& x)
{
    __asm mov x, 10
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    foo(x);
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

but x is still 0 after function execution, however this one works fine

```
int x = 0;
__asm mov x, 10
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

How to solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question – but be advised that your code is not conforming C++, it’s relying on a compiler extension (Visual C++?) so perhaps you could amend your tags to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, it is..added corresponding tag. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reference is a pointer with value semantics - in assembly language these semantics are irrelevant, so you are left with a pointer:

```
void foo(int& x)
{
    __asm { 
        mov eax, x
        mov DWORD PTR [eax], 10
    }
}
```

(Of course, YMMV depending on the compiler, version, optimisations, etc. all the usual stuff when using inline assembly.)

Answer (score 2):

Reference is essentially a pointer, an address of the value, not the value itself.  So this works for example:

```
void foo(int& x)
{
    __asm mov eax, x
    __asm mov dword ptr [eax], 10
}
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: hmm..do we need dword ptr here?

Comment: @ledokol: Yes, otherwise the operand-size is ambiguous.  `mov [eax], 10` could be byte, word, or dword.  Storing zeros or not in the next byte or three is a major difference in semantics.